# Font Awesome: Icons don't appear

Tags: icons, font-awesome

I want to start using Font Awesome as it's much easier to use than icon images, however I'm getting this error when I'm trying to display a icon:

`Font from origin 'http://5.13.X.YYY' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access`

This is the HTML code i'm using:
`<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>`

However the icon displays as a blank square. I'm using XAMPP and I'm hosting the website in my localhost. What can I do?

Edit: I'm linking the stylesheet this way:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

Comment: Show us how you linking `fontawesome` CSS.

Comment: Edited in the main question. I'm using wordpress, by the way. (if helps)

Comment: I want to take a look on `fontawesome` actual path. Not `<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>`. Why don't you see actual path from `View Page Source`?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://5.13.X.YYY/wordpress/wp-content/themes/globestate/css/font-awesome.min.css">`, which is exactly the location it is placed in

Comment: I need to see exact output. Can you share link of DEMO or FIDDLE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by using "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" instead of the path to the font-awesome css placed in my computer.